# Performance of putting together string and char

Tags: c#, .net, types

I wondered if there is any performance impact when I choose to add an one character string or a single char to a constant string.

So I wrote a small Console Application: (.NET 4)

```
static class Program
{
    const string STR = "string ";

    static void Main()
    {
        var arr = new string[99999999];

        Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();

        Console.ReadLine();

        timer.Start();

        //for (uint i = 0; i < 99999999; i++)
        //{
        //  arr[i] = STR + 'C';
        //}

        for (uint i = 0; i < 99999999; i++)
        {
            arr[i] = STR + "C";
        }

        timer.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine(timer.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

You have to comment one for-loop.

So, `STR + "C"` takes around 1300 ms.

For `STR + 'C'` I did not see the result yet. It takes too long and seems to bother my computer pretty hard.

So, my question is. How is this performance impact possible? I know an array of 99999999 values won't occur very often in practical usage, but it's still an enormous difference.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is actually really easy to explain: you've stumbled onto the fact that the C# compiler will perform *constant folding* on string expressions.

Since you declared `STR` to be `const`, that has the effect of replacing references to it with the literal string `"string "`. Then, when the compiler encounters `"string " + "C"`, it replaces that expression with the equivalent `"string C"`. So the loop that actually finishes is spending all its time assigning that string to different positions in the array.

Conversely, the `char` concatenation is *not* optimized that way, so you actually have to wait for both the concatenation (including allocation of the new `string` object) as well as array assignment. As well, the loop will generate a *ton* of garbage, so you're also waiting for the collector.

If you want to compare the two operations fairly, I would do two things:

1. Change the declaration of `STR` to `static readonly` instead of `const`.
2. Reduce the number of iterations, so that you can actually get a full run-through.

Comment: Thank you very much, great answer! Even without constant `STR + "C"` is almost twice as fast as adding a char. So I will use single chararacter strings now. Thanks again!

Comment: @Andy Glad to help. Your observations make sense, since the `string`s can be concatenated directly, rather than having to convert the `char` to a `string` first.

Comment: @Andy That makes sense combined with Tigran's answer: the `+` operator is replaced by the C# compiler with a call to `String.Concat`. When you use it with a string, it can directly call the overload that accepts string parameters. When you use it with a char, it has to box the char and call the overload that accepts an Object parameter. The boxing and unboxing operations are relatively expensive, especially when performed in a tight loop. But beware, this is micro-optimization at its peak!

Comment: @CodyGray I'll second that! If you are in fact concatenating one-character strings in a tight loop, you should definitely be using a `StringBuilder` instead.

Answer (score 4):

The simple program like this:

```
var val = "hello ";     
val += 'r';
```

executes a boxing of `char` value to `object`, which we can see from generated `IL`

```
IL_0001:  ldstr       "hello "
IL_0006:  stloc.0     // val
IL_0007:  ldloc.0     // val
IL_0008:  ldc.i4.s    72 
IL_000A:  box         System.Char
IL_000F:  call        System.String.Concat
IL_0014:  stloc.0     // val
IL_0015:  ldloc.0     // val
```

Instead in case of `string`, there is no any boxing involved, so it's significaly faster.

So why the boxing is executed ? Because calling  [System.String.Concat(String,String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6d350wd.aspx) (that is a result of `binary +` operator call) on 2 arguments where only one of them is a `string`, calls overload of  [String.Concat(object,object)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kbseaaft.aspx), so the value of `char` is boxed to be able to pass into that method call.

Comment: You forgot to explain *why* the char is boxed, but strings are not.